# Error 9002 state 3 after RESTORE DATABASE

Tags: sql-server-2012, restore, errors

I'm trying to restore a database from a validated backup (through RESTORE VERIFYONLY).

The command I've used :

```
RESTORE DATABASE [RESTORE] FILE = N'SharePoint_Config_3c0993c1866f419e9f8e906a920a6ae8' 
FROM  DISK = N'0000008B.bak' 
WITH  
    FILE = 1,  
    MOVE N'SharePoint_Config_3c0993c1866f419e9f8e906a920a6ae8' TO N'F:\RESTORE.mdf',  
    MOVE N'SharePoint_Config_3c0993c1866f419e9f8e906a920a6ae8_log' TO N'F:\RESTORE_log.ldf',  
    NOUNLOAD,  
    REPLACE,  
    STATS = 10
GO
```

At the end of the restore operation, I got this error :

```
...
100 percent processed.
Processed 16888 pages for database 'RESTORE', file 'SharePoint_Config_3c0993c1866f419e9f8e906a920a6ae8' on file 1.
Processed 1707474 pages for database 'RESTORE', file 'SharePoint_Config_3c0993c1866f419e9f8e906a920a6ae8_log' on file 1.
Msg 9004, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
An error occurred while processing the log for database 'RESTORE'.  If possible, restore from backup. If a backup is not available, it might be necessary to rebuild the log.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Then the database is stuck in RESTORING status. The error message suggest to rebuild the log, BUT in RESTORING state I can't do anything : the database can't be accessed for repair with DBCC CHECKDB.

I've tried :

```
RESTORE DATABASE [RESTORE] WITH RECOVERY
GO
```

Result :

```
Msg 4333, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The database cannot be recovered because the log was not restored.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

I've googled It many times, searching on this forum, but can't find a solution to apply suggested procedure "it might be necessary to rebuild the log."

My question is  : how to get rid of this status, ie make the database status to be EMERGENCY so I can try to run repair tools on it ?

Hope somebody can help me.
Regards.

### Update 1

I've managed to get our database in "SUSPECT" status, with Sahnky's tweak. From there, and with some external help, I have run DDBCC CHECKDB with REPAIR_ALLOW_DATALOSS and got our database out of SUSPECT status.

I've omitted to mention that I've tried to RESTORE without the FILE option to perform a full restore, but it hangs with errors (I can't remember which ones).

Comment: @ypercube I've done the request at same time I've posted here, now accounts are merged :)

Comment: Nice, thank you. Deleting the obsolete comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that restore 'verifyonly' does not checks consistency of backup *completely* only a successful restore will guarantee that you backup is in consistent state. There is a option to use Continue_after_error can you please use that in your restore script.

> > RESTORE DATABASE [RESTORE] FILE = N'SharePoint_Config_3c0993c1866f419e9f8e906a920a6ae8' 
> >     FROM  DISK = N'0000008B.bak' 
> >     WITH
> >         FILE = 1,
> >         MOVE N'SharePoint_Config_3c0993c1866f419e9f8e906a920a6ae8' TO N'F:\RESTORE.mdf',
> >         MOVE N'SharePoint_Config_3c0993c1866f419e9f8e906a920a6ae8_log' TO N'F:\RESTORE_log.ldf',
> >         NOUNLOAD,
> >         REPLACE,
> >         STATS = 10,
> >         CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR

Please note that this is a temporary workaround if it works. You should get a fresh backup from production again. Also I highly recommend you to run dbcc checkdb on production database

Answer (score 0):

The RESTORE statement you supplied is a file restore, not a full restore of the database.
You are restoring only the file specified in the FILE clause, in this case the logical file named 'SharePoint_Config_3c0993c1866f419e9f8e906a920a6ae8', and the database cannot be recovered because the transaction log file has not been restored.

You can peruse the Books On-Line page for [File Restores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190710%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) for more detail, and how that differs from a [Complete Database Restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187495%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

I would suggest removing the FILE clause to perform a full restore of the entire database contained in the backup file, i.e.:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [RESTORE]
FROM DISK = N'0000008B.bak' 
WITH
  FILE = 1
  , MOVE N'SharePoint_Config_3c0993c1866f419e9f8e906a920a6ae8' TO N'F:\RESTORE.mdf'
  , MOVE N'SharePoint_Config_3c0993c1866f419e9f8e906a920a6ae8_log' TO N'F:\RESTORE_log.ldf'
  , REPLACE
  , STATS = 10
```